# Onclick not calling method outside of Main Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've a basic email sign up activity. I want to call the register user activity but it wont work unless i place this in the main activity not in my email activity. I think this must be something small but tried loads to get it working with no luck.

EmailActivity.java

```
public class EmailActivity extends  AppCompatActivity {
    //Define the FirebaseAuth and ProgressBar
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initalize the FirebaseAuth and ProgressBar
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_UsrReg);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    //Create a method (registerUser) which will include the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method
    //from the FirebaseAuth object.
    public void registerUser(View view) {
        // get email and password from editTexts
        String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_UserEmail)).getText().toString();
        String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password)).getText().toString();

        // check if email and password are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

activity_email.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EmailActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
       android:onClick="registerUser"
        android:text="@string/btn_Reg" />
```

Login.Activity.java

```
package com.example.android.prototype;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //firebase auth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //getting the firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }
    public void loginUser(View view){
        String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_LogEmail)).getText().toString();
        String password = ((EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.editText_Log_Password)).getText().toString();
     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
 firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ProfileActivity.class));
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    });
}
//Dont have an account need to click on the text and be brought to register page
    public void goRegister (View view){
        startActivity (new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmailActivity.class));
    }
}
```

In my main activity I just launch `setContentView(R.layout.activity_email)`.

Comment: I think you should change tools:context=".MainActivity" to EmailActivity .

Comment: Please add your other activity as well so that we can see what is going on in full detail

Comment: Looks weird. In your `EmailActivity` you have `R.layout.activity_main`. Pls post your `MainActivity` code

Comment: Have changed to make sure EmailActivity is the context. This is the error I get. Could not find method registerUser(View) in a parent or ancestor Context

Answer (score 0):

You are setting  `activity_main`  as layout in your `EmailActivity`: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

This means `EmailActivity` has no business with `activity_email.xml`.

So make sure your `MainActivity` are setting `activity_email.xml` as its layout. And you have a method `public void registerUser(View view)` in your `MainActivity`.